# Countif with a range criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

It's Monday and I must not have had enough coffee. I've been looking around and I can't quite seem to find what I'm looking for. I want to do a countif with a range criteria.

So, for instance, I want to do a count of a range (G:G), based on a range of cells (A81:A97). The items in those cells are detailed business units.

I can't figure out a way to do this. My formula:

=COUNTIF('Beg HC'!G:G,'DBU Map'!A272:A273) is just bringing up '0', which I know isn't right.

Comment: Your question is unclear and it's difficult to understand without some sample data. What I can see is that second parameter (`'DBU Map'!A272:A273`) is surely wrong, Excel can manage only a single cell as a criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in SUM and Array enter the formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF('Beg HC'!G:G,'DBU Map'!A272:A273))
```

Enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: That worked! Thanks - I'm going to accept it in 8 minutes. Why didn't the way I wrote it work? I'm just curious.

Comment: As I stated you need to tell excel what to do with counts, You need to wrap it in SUM so it knows to sum the different counts.  You could just as easily wrap it in MIN and it will return the MIN and so forth.  The Ctrl-Shift-Enter tells the COUNTIF to iterate the criteria.